# Set theory, intersection of two sets

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

We have the set $D$ which consists of $x$, where $x$ is a prime number. We also have the set F, which consists of $x$, belongs to the natural numbers (positive numbers $1, 2, 3, 4, 5,\dots$) that is congruent with 1 (modulo 8). What numbers are in the intersection of these two sets?

So the set $F$ consists of numbers that when divided by $8$ gives the remainder 1. So, 1, 9, 17, 25, 33, 41, and so on. The set $D$ is prime numbers. So: 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 and so on. I am to find the numbers that are in both of these sets. But how can I do this? I have no idea except for making a long list of numbers and matching them.

Comment: There are infinitely many primes which are congruent to $1 \pmod{8}$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions So what exactly is it required from you?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A007519

Comment: I think I have to express it in some way. But I wouldn't know how to begin or do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can only test whether a given number is prime or not using bunch of tests including but not limited to $\textbf{Wilson's Theorem}$ and $\textbf{Euler phi function}$ $\large{\phi(p) \overset{?}{=} p-1}$, You can check more about [primality testing here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test)

Here is the thing, there is no formula that generates a prime number, all you can do in your case is the following.

Since you know that set $F$ consists of natural numbers that are congruence to 1 modulo 8. That is to say , if $a \in F$ then $a \geq 1$ and  $a \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$ and so $$a \equiv 1 \pmod{8} \implies 8 \mid a -1$$ and so there must exists an integer $k$ such that $8k =a -1$ and so $a = 8k + 1$.

Now since we know that $a \geq 1$ so $k=0,1,2,3,.....$ so choosing any $k \in \big[0,1,2,3,..... \big]$ will get you an $a \in F$. Now this is not enough, you want to test whether $a$ is prime to determine whether it intersects in both sets $D$ and $F$.

And so you do the following, after you get $k$ you will get an $a\in F$ in the form of $a = 8k+1$ then you take this and test if $\phi(8k+1) = 8k$ for instance and if this is true then they intersect.

Or you can test using Wilson's theorem.

Wilson theorem states that a number $p$ is prime if and only if $\color{red}{(p-1)!\equiv  -1 \pmod{p}}$ and so applying this to $a = 8k + 1$ we get the following $a$ is prime if and only if $$ (8k)! \equiv -1 \pmod{8k + 1}$$.

In summary , if you get $a = 8k +1$ where $k$ is non negative and $8k + 1$ satisfying wilson's theorem or euler phi function then $a \in D \cap F$. I hope that you get the idea now !